# CSS Auto Div Height

Tags: html, css, height

Good day to all.

I would like to ask assistant on the issue I am having with my site which I could not get fixed. http://inview.wpengine.com/home (don't mind its homepage - its just a temporary html landing page) It's a 2-column template (Left: Content ; Right: Sidebar) which I customized from the TwentyEleven WP theme. As you can see, there is a white space between the content on the left column which supposed to be have same bg as the ones with contents. Both sides have same Issues everytime one of the column has lesser content compared to the other side.

I know this question has been answered a few times on other posts but I can't seem to get it work and I am hoping somebody can help me fix it. Thank you so much.

Comment: See this disscussion, here is same problem solution for division.[click here][1] Hope,it will helps you. !! [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792583/css-auto-resize-div

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your two columns

```
style="position: relative;overflow: hidden;"
```

Comment: hi, thank you for replying...I will try this one and will let you know if this works... :)